# Determine if user clicked the home button/app is not active[Firefox OS]

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-os

Is there a way to determine if the user clicked the home button/application-is-not-active in Firefox OS? I used `window.onblur`, yes it works but it always fires when I clicked the panel at the top even though my app is still drawn on the screen/active. Im using a Firefox OS Simulator by the way. Thanks

Comment: Don't know about Firefox OS, will [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) help?

Comment: thank you, thats what im looking for :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is the code you need:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
    if (document.hidden) {
        console.log("App is hidden");
    }
    else {
        console.log("App has focus");
    }
});
```